# Javascript Stored Variable after page refresh

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm having a problem relating to storing a variable within Javascript. I have a web monitoring page (I have written the code which works), which refreshes automatically every 5 mins.

If one of the sites I am monitoring goes down, the JS sends an email to the admin, but I only want to send this once.

My logic was to:

> Check if a site is down
>    if variable emailPreviouslySent == 'no'
>    then send email to admin
>    write to variable emailPreviouslySent = 'yes'
>
> *Page would refresh*
>
> Check if a site is down
>    emailPreviouslySent == 'yes'
>
> email would not be sent again

However I'm finding that the variable is emptied each time the page refreshes.

Is there a way of carrying the variable even though the page is refreshing, or perhaps another way around this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried cookies ?

Comment: You can usecookies, or HTML5 local storage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However I'm finding that the variable is emptied each time the page
>   refreshes.

You are inside **state-less HTTP** request. Store your variable in cookie to retain its value even after page refresh but notice that a cookie can be deleted by a user too.

Or as rightly suggested by @Matt Ball, a better approach would be to use HTML5's [`localStorage`](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/) feature.

Comment: That fast, thanks.

Not looked into cookies, however that may be the way to go, as I'm (sadly) forced to use IE.

Comment: May I suggest taking a look at store.js (https://github.com/frankkohlhepp/store-js), it makes using `localStorage` nice and easy. And I believe it has solutions for working with IE6 and above :-)

Comment: @BenEverard: Ah have used that, it does the job well. Thanks for adding.